# Why does kubernetes internally use string pointers rather than strings？

Tags: go

Not only string pointers but also bool pointers, int pointers, etc.

See: 
https://github.com/kubernetes/cli-runtime/blob/5c4694c3aa38d6f710b2e3b18598f9d83f1aae3b/pkg/genericclioptions/config_flags.go#L322-L336

It seems like golang can't get benefits from something like Constant Pool.

Golang

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func StringPtr(s string) *string {
    return &s
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(StringPtr("")) // outputs "0x40e128"
    fmt.Println(StringPtr("")) // outputs "0x40e138"
}
```

Python

```
id("") // outputs "4459080368"
id("") // outputs "4459080368"
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it's made this way to be sure that the config flags' values are updated everywhere if changed.

This example may be helpful

```
package main

import "fmt"

func stringPointer(s string) *string {
    return &s
}

type Config struct {
    String  string
    Pointer *string
}

func NewConfig() Config {
    return Config{
        String:  "default",
        Pointer: stringPointer("default"),
    }
}

var (
    config = NewConfig()

    String  = config.String
    Pointer = config.Pointer
)

func PrintVars() {
    fmt.Printf("config.String: %v\n", config.String)
    fmt.Printf("config.Pointer: %v\n", *config.Pointer)
    fmt.Printf("String: %v\n", String)
    fmt.Printf("Pointer: %v\n", *Pointer)
    fmt.Println("-------------------------")
}

func main() {
    PrintVars()
    config.String = "new value"
    *config.Pointer = "new value"
    PrintVars()
    String = "even newer value"
    *Pointer = "even newer value"
    PrintVars()
}
```

out:

```
config.String: default
config.Pointer: default
String: default
Pointer: default
-------------------------
config.String: new value
config.Pointer: new value
String: default
Pointer: new value
-------------------------
config.String: new value
config.Pointer: even newer value
String: even newer value
Pointer: even newer value
-------------------------
```

Comment: It is OK if you do everything in one goroutine. If you update  *config.Pointer in one goroutine and read it in another goroutine in your way it is a data race. You need to have a mutex as well to avoid the data race.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the purpose of using int pointers instead of int in config(like kubernetes spec) is to distinguish between explicit zero and not specified, the same as string
or bool. You can find this in https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/api-design.html

Answer (score 0):

To store a string, you need 2 words of computer memory. One of them points to the start of the string, the other contains the length.

A string pointer is only half the size, since it's just a pointer, without the length. This saves memory.

When you have 100 pointers to the same string, this difference becomes apparent. Then you have 100 + 2 words plus the actual byte array. This of course depends on whether `newstring` interns the strings.

Using string pointers instead of strings has another use case. The program can then distinguish between an empty string and no string at all. Especially in the configuration section, this is useful. Having a timeout of 0 seconds is different from having no timeout at all. For most of the other configuration options an empty string would not make sense anyway, so this is just overhead. Still, it is structured this way to have the same structure for each configuration option. This consistency helps when you need to understand the code.

There may be other reasons as well. Maybe there's some project documentation about this topic.

Comment: `A string pointer is only half the size, since it's just a pointer, without the length. `. Is it correct? I think the string pointer just points to the 2 words of computer memory which actually contains an pointer and a lenght

Comment: @SergeiKurenkov When you have 100 pointers to the same string, this difference becomes apparent. Then you have 100 + 2 words plus the actual byte array. This of course depends on whether `newstring` interns the strings.

Comment: The memory usage angle is completely irrelevant in all but the tiniest fraction of cases. It saves you the size of a single `int` per case where you copy a pointer to the same, non-interned string. The latter paragraph regarding detecting the difference between an empty string and an unspecified one is far more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

An attribute pointer gives the attribute another value:

```
type config struct {
   PtrValue *string
   Value    string
}
```

The pointers to basic type variables are great for cases where an empty string `("")` would have a different meaning than the `nil` value.

For example, a command line program's input arguments have no guarantee that a user provides such input. The pointer value is an ideal way to distinguish between no input and zero value input.